# Change of variables in two variables limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

My exercise book often uses, when possible, substitution in two variables limits in order to then use one-variable limits. This process isn't very clear to me: aside from the cases in which the substitution is in the form $x^2 +y^2$, in which proving that one implies the other isn't very hard, I have a hard time seeing that the fact that one implies the other is always true. To make my point clear, here's one example:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(xy)}{x^2y^2}$$
Is it always true that this kind of substitution works? Why?

Comment: You have $g(f(x,y))$ where $f(x,y)=xy$ and $g(u)=(1-\cos(u))/u^{2}$, and you want $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}g(f(x,y))$. The problem in your case is that $xy\ne 0$ for all $0 < |(x,y)| < \delta$ for some $\delta$. So, you should probably define $g(0)=\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}g(u)$ in order to make full sense of this problem. Then you can show that the desired limit exists by studying the composition of $g$ and $f$.